# NSUserDefaults already has key and value pairs? -swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am using NSUserDefaults in my application and when I start the application, the NSUserDefaults appears to already have default values. When I print the NSUserDefaults at the beginning of my app as a dictionary, it has default values. This is what printing it as a dictionary looks like:

```
[MSVLoggingMasterSwitchEnabledKey: 0, NSLanguages: (
en,
fr,
de,
"zh-Hans",
"zh-Hant",
ja,
nl,
it,
es,
"es-MX",
ko,
pt,
"pt-PT",
da,
fi,
nb,
sv,
ru,
pl,
tr,
uk,
ar,
hr,
cs,
el,
he,
ro,
sk,
th,
id,
ms,
"en-GB",
"en-AU",
ca,
hu,
vi,
hi
), AppleITunesStoreItemKinds: (
audiobook,
"tv-episode",
booklet,
software,
"software-update",
"itunes-u",
ringtone,
"tv-season",
movie,
mix,
newsstand,
song,
wemix,
tone,
artist,
"podcast-episode",
podcast,
document,
eBook,
album,
"music-video"
), AppleKeyboardsExpanded: 1, NSInterfaceStyle: macintosh, AppleKeyboards: (
"en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY",
"emoji@sw=Emoji",
"en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY"
), AppleLocale: en_US, AppleLanguages: (
en,
fr,
de,
"zh-Hans",
"zh-Hant",
ja,
nl,
it,
es,
"es-MX",
ko,
pt,
"pt-PT",
da,
fi,
nb,
sv,
ru,
pl,
tr,
uk,
ar,
hr,
cs,
el,
he,
ro,
sk,
th,
id,
ms,
"en-GB",
"en-AU",
ca,
hu,
vi,
hi
)]
[MSVLoggingMasterSwitchEnabledKey: 0, NSLanguages: (
en,
fr,
de,
"zh-Hans",
"zh-Hant",
ja,
nl,
it,
es,
"es-MX",
ko,
pt,
"pt-PT",
da,
fi,
nb,
sv,
ru,
pl,
tr,
uk,
ar,
hr,
cs,
el,
he,
ro,
sk,
th,
id,
ms,
"en-GB",
"en-AU",
ca,
hu,
vi,
hi
), AppleITunesStoreItemKinds: (
audiobook,
"tv-episode",
booklet,
software,
"software-update",
"itunes-u",
ringtone,
"tv-season",
movie,
mix,
newsstand,
song,
wemix,
tone,
artist,
"podcast-episode",
podcast,
document,
eBook,
album,
"music-video"
), AppleKeyboardsExpanded: 1, NSInterfaceStyle: macintosh,        
AppleKeyboards: (
"en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY",
"emoji@sw=Emoji",
"en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY"
), AppleLocale: en_US, AppleLanguages: (
en,
fr,
de,
"zh-Hans",
"zh-Hant",
ja,
nl,
it,
es,
"es-MX",
ko,
pt,
"pt-PT",
da,
fi,
nb,
sv,
ru,
pl,
tr,
uk,
ar,
hr,
cs,
el,
he,
ro,
sk,
th,
id,
ms,
"en-GB",
"en-AU",
ca,
hu,
vi,
hi
)]
[MSVLoggingMasterSwitchEnabledKey: 0, NSLanguages: (
en,
fr,
de,
"zh-Hans",
"zh-Hant",
ja,
nl,
it,
es,
"es-MX",
ko,
pt,
"pt-PT",
da,
fi,
nb,
sv,
ru,
pl,
tr,
uk,
ar,
hr,
cs,
el,
he,
ro,
sk,
th,
id,
ms,
"en-GB",
"en-AU",
ca,
hu,
vi,
hi
), AppleITunesStoreItemKinds: (
audiobook,
"tv-episode",
booklet,
software,
"software-update",
"itunes-u",
ringtone,
"tv-season",
movie,
mix,
newsstand,
song,
wemix,
tone,
artist,
"podcast-episode",
podcast,
document,
eBook,
album,
"music-video"
), AppleKeyboardsExpanded: 1, NSInterfaceStyle: macintosh,    
AppleKeyboards: (
"en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY",
"emoji@sw=Emoji",
"en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY"
), AppleLocale: en_US, AppleLanguages: (
en,
fr,
de,
"zh-Hans",
"zh-Hant",
ja,
nl,
it,
es,
"es-MX",
ko,
pt,
"pt-PT",
da,
fi,
nb,
sv,
ru,
pl,
tr,
uk,
ar,
hr,
cs,
el,
he,
ro,
sk,
th,
id,
ms,
"en-GB",
"en-AU",
ca,
hu,
vi,
hi
)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for languages there are some preset values. As you have indicated, the items you have pasted are languages. Even items in quotes such as "zh-Hans" are referring to languages, in this case different dialects of Chinese.

It is noted on [gnustep.org](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/Reference/NSUserDefaults.html) that "The NSLanguages default value is used to set up the constants for localization."

Comment: so how would I start a NSUserDefaults with no default values?

Comment: user3798602, as gnustep.org mentioned, the NSLanguages default value is used to set up the constants for localization. We don't have the power to stop that part of things. However, if localization is not being done, we can simply ignore them.

If you want your own app to have a "fresh start" you could make a list of the nsuserdefaults that your app uses. Then you can run through them in code and set them all to null or zeroed out values. That would effectively give you "no" default values.